# Getting ClassNotFoundException on code: "Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");"

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception, sqljdbc

This is my first *Java* application and I'm completely inexperienced with *Java* and *NetBeans*.

I have been trying to connect to sql and get some records for 2 days. The problem is about *jdbc* driver, let me explain. I have downloaded *sqljdbc* driver and then followed these steps:

Right-click Project->Select Properties->On the left-hand side click Libraries->Under Compile tab - click Add Jar/Folder button and select *sqljdbc4.jar* file. Then it should be ok, right?

Then I wrote this code But I cant get rid of  this exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:30)
```

This is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://.\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Northwind; Integrated Security = SSPI ";

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sql = "Select Top 3 from * person.Contact";
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx), the class is called `SQLServerDriver` and not `SqlServerDriver`. Case is important!

So, try:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Note that with newer versions of JDBC, it's not necessary to load the driver class explicitly with `Class.forName(...)`. The page I linked to explicitly explains that you don't have to do it. So, you can just remove the whole line and then it should work.

Comment: I have been working on this problem for days started mybe ten thread in diffrent forums and formatted my machine 3 times what can i say thank you soooo muchh Jesper

Comment: I have the same problem. but after removing this line, i have another error about, suitable driver not being found. do you know the reason?

Comment: @ConductedClever Why did you remove the line if that makes your application not work? A "no suitable driver found" error can also mean that your JDBC URL is not correct. (The JDBC driver JAR must also be in your classpath when you run the application).

Comment: @Jesper, I am still getting the exception, even though I had already taken care of case sensitivity while typing the class name. I am posting my code in the next comment:

Comment: import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseConnectivity {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
  
  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  
  Connection m_Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address:1433;DatabaseName=DB_Name", "username", "password");

  
  System.out.println("Connection successful!!!");
      Statement m_Statement = m_Connection.createStatement();
      String query = "SELECT * FROM CI_Item";
 }
}

Comment: @Vikram Make sure that the JDBC driver jar file is in your classpath when you run your application.

Comment: Class.forName() did it for me in that after using it, I got an error message telling me that the SQLServer JDBC jar I was using was too new for Java 8, which we're still running on some of our servers.  I switched to an older jar, and my application began to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Java: JDBC Connectivity with MSSQL in NetBeans**

Steps

1. Download JDBC from:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11774
2. Run sqljdbc__enu.exe - unpack this zip file in %Program
   Files (x86)% with the default directory:    Microsoft JDBC DRIVER
    for SQL Server
3. Create your new project in NetBeans
4. Right Click on the project - select Properties - select Libraries
   from left panel - click Add JAR/Folder button - select your JAR file
   and open - ok
5. Open Sql Server Configuration Manager - select Protocols for
   SQLEXPRESS under Sql Server Network Configuration - Right Click on
   TCP/IP - select Properties - change Enable to Yes - Click IP
   Addresses - Goto IPAll - Change TCP Dynamic Ports to 49169 and TCP
   Port to 1433 - Apply - Ok - Restart the Computer
6. Open Run and type Services.msc - Start SQL Server Browser
7. Goto project and write code for database connectivity.

**Code for Local Database Connectivity:**

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://YOUR PC NAME;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true";

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

Statement myStmt = myCon.createStatement();
ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from table name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an update about this issue.

1. Go to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#java-and-jdbc-specification-support) link, find your compatible JDBC driver (I dowloaded 6.0 version).
2. Find the appropriate jar in the file you downloaded (I used jre7\sqljdbc41.jar).
3. For Intellij Idea press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S` and open Project Structure then in the dependencies section add your jar file.

I hope it works for you too.