# ClassNotFoundException - com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, driver, classnotfoundexception

I have a web development project using local install of `Tomcat 7`.  I am trying to connect to `SQL Server 2012` using Microsoft's driver for jdbc (`sqljdbc41.jar`).

The `sqljdbc41.jar` is in my application build path:

[image]

and I am exporting it.  Furthermore, in the Tomcat application directory `lib` folder I have also placed a copy of `sqljdbc41.jar`.

There are no compile errors, but at runtime when I try to load the SQL Server driver I get the following:

```
ClassNotFoundException - com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

The exception is thrown in the following code block:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+":1433;databaseName="+database+";user=sa;password="+password+";";
con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

I have seen many posts on this topic without resolution:

1. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver : Am I loading the right driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461040/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver)
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b425c201-9882-4a48-b049-4004f202b0c6/javalangclassnotfoundexception-commicrosoftsqlserverjdbcsqlserverdriver?forum=sqldataaccess
3. [Getting ClassNotFoundException on code: "Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420675/getting-classnotfoundexception-on-code-class-fornamecom-microsoft-sqlserver)

and many more.

Compiler level 1.7 and a JRE of 1.7 - According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526(v=sql.110).aspx), I believe I am using the correct driver.  This also states that the CLASSPATH must be set:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
/var/common/sqljdbc41.jar
```

Which it is.  Furthermore:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM)
64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

So, why am I still encountering this???

> Update

I downloaded the `sqljdbc41.jar` from Microsoft again - just to be sure that somehow the first jar was not corrupt.

Following Mick Mnemonic's link, I removed the jar from the Java Build path and put the newly downloaded jar into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the web application.  I then restarted Eclipse and the Tomcat server and cleaned the Tomcat server, and the project.

Still getting the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Also, the Eclipse IDE can see the driver:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the package structure of the jar already ? Is jtds an option ?

Comment: @Marged  Yes, and I can see that particular driver in the archive.

Comment: Have you tried a newer version ? As far as I know a version > 4.1 is available. Using jTDS is not an option ?

Comment: @Marged I am using 4.1 thus `sqljdbc41.jar`.  I am not sure that's an option yet.  I will check into it.  Thanks, I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: Tomcat will explicitly unset and re-initialize the `CLASSPATH` variable when it starts up. You probably just need to add the library to `catalina.properties` as instructed in [this blog post](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath).

Comment: @MickMnemonic  Curious that I need to set the classpath at all since I have the jar physically in the Tomcat `lib` folder.  It should find it there like all other jars I use in the project that are not a part of JDK.

Comment: Did you add the path-to-lib into `catalina.properties`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic - No I did no.  Since the jar is in Tomcat's `Lib` folder, that should not be necessary.

Comment: Are you using Maven? If yes, in the Deployment assembly have you added "Maven Dependencies" as deploy path WEB-INF/lib? (To accomplish. right click on project, go in Properties -> Deployment assembly and add "Maven dependencies"

Comment: @JoeTaras - No Maven.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question or your code?  You are getting an exception `ClassNotFoundException - com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` looking in jdbc.sqlserver but your import lists sqlserver.jdbc

Comment: I was able to get it to work by simply dropping `sqljdbc41.jar` into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder for the project and letting Eclipse discover it. In Project Explorer it looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N3nie.png). When you open the Properties dialog for the project and look at the "Libraries" tab of the "Java Build Path" page do you see the driver .jar under "Web App Libraries" like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X5yoa.png)?

Comment: BTW, when I said "letting Eclipse discover it" I was referring to right-clicking the project name in the Project Explorer tree and choosing "Refresh". That's all it took for me.

Answer (score 8):

The code
`Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`

cannot throw 
`ClassNotFoundException - com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`

as the names are different.  Is it possible that you have it set up incorrectly in your code?

I downloaded the sqljdbc41.jar from their website and see that the correct name for the class is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.

```
$ jar tf sqljdbc41.jar | grep SQLServerDriver.class
com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.class
```

I just found both names on Microsoft's web documentation, so either they renamed this class (changed its package) at some point, or they have errors on some of their docs.

All you should need to do is drop that .jar in Tomcat's lib directory (e.g.`apache-tomcat-7.0.67\lib`), and restart Tomcat.

If you have the correct class name, and the right jar in the lib directory, and are still seeing that error, I wonder if you have some sort of typo in your eclipse setup, and deploying from eclipse is somehow forcing an attempt to load that broken class name. (I don't use Eclipse, and I don't know about deploying from there).

Try creating a very simple application (and don't tell eclipse about the MS driver class):

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + "Welcome to the servlet!" + "</h1>");
        try {
            String server = "localhost";
            String database = "testDB";
            String password = "sapassword";

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+":1433;databaseName="+database+";user=sa;password="+password+";";
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            out.println("<h2>" + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + e.getMessage() + "</h2>");
        } catch (SQLException e){
            out.println("<h2>" + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + e.getMessage() + "</h2>");
        } finally {
            out.println("<h1>" + "That's the end of the servlet!" + "</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

And running it.  If you see output like:

```
Welcome to the servlet!

SQLServerException_The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

That's the end of the servlet!
```

It means that the driver loaded properly.  The connection failed b/c I don't have SQLServer instance currently running to test against.

Comment: We found the solution, but because there was a bounty on this post, I was not allowed to delete it, and have been away for several days.  There was a hard-coding that was basically ignoring what was being passed in.  But you are correct and that subtlety was missed before offering the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the library to catalina.properties because you are using the DB connection within the context of the container's core functionality, and not just as one of the child applications inside it.

Downvote my answer as you wish, but I only ask you test it first.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at all the comments here on this post, I assume that you've tried almost all the options provided. Looking at your snapshots provided above, I assume you are using a Unix/Linux based system for your development. There is a change in the way you update your CLASSPATH variable in Windows and say in Linux. *';'* is used in Windows while *':'* in Linux. Hope you've taken care of such minor details:

There's a helpful link that I can suggest you to go through, where there are many remedies given to resolve the issue that you are facing: [Link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/07/javalangclassnotfoundexception-com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be registered on the dialect class: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

if it were spring project, it is connected to a file application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver:database;user=sa;password=password;
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=password
```

but here it will be exactly like I do not remember